# Extend PBR_Image volume

Tags: 13.10, partitioning

I am very new to linux, and got a message everytime I boot my computer.
I have got a dual boot with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10
The message I got:

[image: screenshot message]

My partitions:
[image: screenshot partitions]

So I have a backup partitions(used in windows), can I use some GB of that and "extend the PBR_image"?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to shrink partition 6, move partition 7 to the left, then you could grow partition 8 into that free space.  You can do this using gparted when booting from the Ubuntu desktop cd.

Comment: I have booted into gparted while booting from the disk, and used gparted to shrink a volume(14.50GB). [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gJDyVMB.png) but i am unable to add this to my pbr_image. The options i get are: delete,
resize/move,
copy,
format to >,
manage flags,
check,
label,
new UUID,
information, right clicking on unallocated spce will only give to option new or information

Comment: @GuusvanWalstijn, you didn't move partition 7 to the left.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont know what you mean with "move the partition to the left". I cant select it and move it to the left?

Comment: @GuusvanWalstijn, right click on the partition and pick move/resize, and slide it to the left.